# Mylyn connector for Assembla on Eclipse fails to setup

Tags: eclipse-plugin, mylyn, assembla

I'm developing with Eclipse Indigo and using Assembla.

I use [Mylyn](http://eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/) and the [Assembla connector for Mylyn](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/assemblamylyn/How_To_Use). The connector fails to create a task repository.

When I create a new task repository, after filling in the server (happens both on http and https), the user and password, the results is always a blank spaces list under additional settings.
The error message is:
"No Assembla repository found at url: Cannot get space name from url"

I do understand that Assembla is no longer supporting this plugin.

I'm looking for solution or a workaround for the problem or an alternative plugin to Assembla (I'm bound to use Assembla and can't move to a alternative service).

My environment: Ubuntu 11.10 64bit, Eclipse Indigo, Tigris Subclipse plugin.

Thanks, David.

Comment: What happens if you push the "Update Spaces from Repository" button?  If you push the "Validate" button?

Comment: @Kaitlin When pushing the "Update Spaces from Repository" I get a msg: "Space is not selected".
When pushing "Validate", I get the msg mentioned in my post, "No Assembla repository found at url: Cannot get space name from url"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a fix available for this problem [here](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/assemblamylyn/documents/). This an archive update site, the remote update site does not yet contain this version, but it should soon.

Comment: @ Brett Thanks! this actually worked. I unzipped the plugin from your link and added the folder under ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/dropins
I managed to (1) preview my tickets, (2) create a new ticket and see it from the web.

Comment: @Brett Sadly, this plugin has other (authentication) issues now. See the [issue](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/assemblamylyn/tickets/34#/activity/ticket:) opened on Assembla. Your help would be appreciated